# Combining an external site with services behind subdirectories served by Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

**Objective**

I have the following I wish to host under a single subdomain `https://sub.example.com`:

1. An external Wix site, which should be accessible at the root subdomain `https://sub.example.com`
2. An API accessible through AWS API Gateway, which should be accessible at `https://sub.example.com/api`
3. A flat static site in a restricted AWS S3 bucket, which should be accessible at `https://sub.example.com/docs/`

**Attempted solution**

I'm having trouble combining all this in AWS Cloudfront and Route 53. So far, I've tried setting up a Cloudfront distribution with the following default origins and behaviours:

1. Origin: `https://username.wix.com/website` (root domain as Origin domain and `/website` as Origin Path). Behaviour: Path as `Default (*)`
2. Origin: API Gateway Invoke URL (stage is Origin Path). Behaviour: Path as `/api*`.
3. Origin: S3 bucket domain. Behaviour: Path as `/docs*`.

In Route 53 I have the `sub.example.com` A and AAAA records pointing at the Cloudfront distribution domain.

**Problems**

I'm running into a few issues here:

1. Redirection of the Wix site is imperfect. Cloudfront hides the Wix domain at the root, but then redirects to the Wix domain for any subdirectories (e.g. `https://sub.example.com/about`. Also, when specifying `index.html` as Default root object (this is needed for the S3 static site), the Wix site 404s.
2. API calls work perfectly fine at `https://sub.example.com/api/`, but for some reason, the S3 static site is inaccessible (Access Denied) at `https://sub.example.com/docs/`, even when the Default root object is set as `index.html`.

Regarding Problem 1, I acknowledge that Cloudfront is not really meant for proxying external sites, but I'm not really sure how to otherwise keep this site at the root subdomain, especially since a `Default (*)` behaviour is mandatory.

Regarding Problem 2, I'm left a bit flummoxed. I tested all policies and OAIs using a separate distribution to the S3 bucket and confirmed that this is all correct. The Behaviour precedence is also correctly set (0: `/docs*`, 1: `/api*`, 2: `*`).

Regarding both these problems, I wonder if there may be some Route 53 wizardry that can partly solve them. Perhaps solutions can be found in Cloudfront Functions or Lambda@Edge. However, I'm not very experienced at these.

Any advice would be very welcome.